# Open source tool to synchronize data between different data centers

Tags: synchronization, regions

Anybody knows the tools to synchronize the data between different data centres located across different regions?

Answer (score 0):

That's a terribly vague question. But going on one possible interpretation, `rsync`, `rdist`, and `unison` come to mind, but I'm sure there's plenty more. It depends on whether you need real-time synchronization, one- or two-way synchronization, what your network bandwidth is and many other things.